# naming convention: What is the difference between "from" vs "of" methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, naming-conventions

From naming conventions and usability:
What is the difference between "from" vs "of" methods in a class? when to create each one?

Comment: Why is this opinion-based? We have growing consensus on this rather important topic, with expanding usage.

Comment: @BasilBourque, if the question had been asked specifically in the context of the Java Date-Time API, your answer would be authoritative. As it stands, there is no universal standard, or even convention, that a programmer could expect to find across all of Java. Each company and even each team will define their own convention, as did the Oracle team responsible for Date-Time.

Comment: According to "effective java":

-- from(): A type-conversion method that takes a single parameter and returns a corresponding instance of this type.

-- of(): An aggregation method that takes multiple parameters and returns an in- stance of this type that incorporates them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the guide [*Method Naming Conventions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html) posted as part of [the *java.time* tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) provide by Oracle.

To quote:

> `of`
>
> Creates an instance where the factory is primarily validating the input parameters, not converting them.

… and …

> `from`
>
> Converts the input parameters to an instance of the target class, which may involve losing information from the input.

For realistic examples, see the *java.time* classes such as [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html), [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html), [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), `LocalDateTime`, and so on.

```java
LocalDate x = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.MARCH , 27 ) ;  // Directly injecting the three parts of a date (year, month, day) without any need to parse or process the inputs other than basic data validation such as day within appropriate range of 1-28/31 for that year-month.

ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;       // This string is the official name of this time zone. Can be mapped directly from name to object, with no real processing, parsing, or conversions involved.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ) ;
LocalDate y = LocalDate.from( zdt ) ;                    // Converting between types. Data loss involved, losing (a) time-of-day and (b) time zone.
LocalDate z = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

See [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/WEshOk).

```
x.toString(): 2021-03-27
y.toString(): 2021-05-25
z.toString(): 2021-05-25
```